# SQL query returning false in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform this query in PHP however it keeps returning false. I have tried the query in phpMyAdmin and it works fine so if anyone can spot what is wrong that would be great. Also how can I get some better error messages for problems like this so I can try and solve the problem?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?;");
if(!$stmt)
{
    echo "Error creating SQL statement";
    return 1;
}
```

I have already used `$stmt = $conn->prepare(query);` for a different query in the same block of PHP code which runs fine so I don't know if that is anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I was asked where I bind the '?' used in the query. `$stmt->bind_param('i', $albumArtID);` I didn't include it in the question originally because the `echo` in the `if` statement runs so I presumed it was encountering an error before the `bind_param`.

EDIT 2: As requested here is the code used to make the connection:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'psyjb6';

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'psyjb6');
if ($conn->connect_errno)
    echo"<p>failed to connect to database</p>";
?>
```

EDIT 3: Here is the entire main section of code from that page, hopefully we can figure this out:

```
<form name="editAlbum" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">

                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                            error_reporting(E_ALL);
                            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                            include 'connection.php';

                            if(isset($_GET["album"]))
                            {
                                /* If album was passed in the URL then get current values
                                    for that album */
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cd.artID, artName, cdTitle, cdPrice, cdGenre, cdTracks FROM cd INNER JOIN artist ON (cd.artID = artist.artID AND cdID = ?);");
                                if(!$stmt)
                                {
                                    echo "Error creating SQL statement";
                                    exit;
                                }

                                $albumID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["album"]);

                                $stmt->bind_param('i', $albumID);
                                $stmt->execute();

                                $stmt->bind_result($albumArtID, $albumArtName, $albumTitle,
                                                   $albumPrice, $albumGenre, $numTracks);

                                $stmt->fetch();

                                /* Create input fields */
                                // Album Title
                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" . 
                                    "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumTitle) . "\" name=\"albumTitle\"/>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                // Artist Name
                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
                                        "<h6>By Artist:</h6>" .
                                        "</div>";

                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
                                        "<select name=\"artID\">";

                                /* Create option for current artist so it will be first in list */
                                echo "<option value=\"$albumArtID\">$albumArtName</option>\n";

                                /* Generate list of artists except artist currently associated with the album */
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?");
                                if($stmt === false)
                                {
                                    echo $conn->error;
                                    echo "hi";
                                    exit;
                                }

                                $stmt->bind_param('i', $albumArtID);
                                $stmt->execute();

                                $stmt->bind_result($artID, $artName);

                                /* Check if no artists were found */
                                if(!$stmt->fetch())
                                    echo "<p>No artists were found!</p>";
                                else
                                {
                                    /* Create options for artists that were found */
                                    do
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"$artID\">$artName</option>\n";
                                    }while($stmt->fetch());
                                }

                                echo "</select>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                // Album Price
                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
                                        "<input type=\"number\" step=\"0.01\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumPrice) . "\" name=\"albumPrice\"/>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                // Album Genre
                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" . 
                                        "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumGenre) . "\" name=\"albumGenre\"/>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                // Number of Tracks
                                echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" . 
                                        "<input type=\"number\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($numTracks) . "\" name=\"numTracks\"\n/>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                // Delete checkbox
                                echo "<div class=\"row\">" .
                                        "<div class=\"col-2\">" .
                                            "<h6>Delete:</h6>" .
                                        "</div>" .
                                        "<div class=\"col-1\">" .
                                            "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\"/>" .
                                        "</div>" .
                                    "</div>";

                                /* Create hidden field to submit the album ID with the form */
                                echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumID) . "\" name=\"albumID\"\n/>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                /* Send browser back to artists page if they somehow accessed
                                    the edit page without going through the "Edit" link next
                                    to an artist in the table. This would be the artName variable
                                    would not be sent via the URL.*/
                                header("Location: artists.php");
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <h6>Delete:</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
                        </div>      

                        <!-- PHP to edit album data -->
                        <?php
                        include 'connection.php';                                               

                        if(isset($_GET["delete"]))
                        {
                            $albumID = $_GET["albumID"];

                            /* Create DELETE query */
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cd WHERE cdID = ?;");
                            if(!$stmt)
                            {
                                echo "Error creating SQL statement";
                                exit;
                            }

                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $albumID);

                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                        else if(isset($_GET["albumTitle"]) && isset($_GET["albumGenre"])
                            && isset($_GET["albumPrice"]) && isset($_GET["numTracks"]))
                        {
                            $albumTitle = htmlspecialchars($_GET["albumTitle"]);
                            $artID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["artID"]);
                            $albumGenre = htmlspecialchars($_GET["albumGenre"]);
                            $albumPrice = htmlspecialchars($_GET["albumPrice"]);
                            $numTracks = htmlspecialchars($_GET["numTracks"]);

                            /* Create INSERT query */
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cd SET (cdTitle = ?, artID = ?,
                                cdGenre = ?, cdPrice = ?, cdTracks = ?) WHERE cdID = ?;");
                            if(!$stmt)
                            {
                                echo "Error creating SQL statement";
                                exit;
                            }

                            $stmt->bind_param('sisdi', $albumTitle, $artID, $albumGenre,
                                                $albumPrice, $numTracks);

                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                        ?>  

                    </form>
```

Comment: Where do you bind the value which is compared with `artID`?

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`? If you are not sure, show us the code you use to make a connection

Comment: @AlBundy Updated the question to show it.

Comment: Please create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order we have chance to help you.

Comment: @AlBundy how on earth can I do that when to run this code there needs be a database for you to access?

Comment: `->prepare` returns `FALSE` when an error occurred. See [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). This means, there is no table `artist` in the current selected database or there is no field `artID` in the table `artist` or, you do not have permissions to read from the table. There must be a MySQL error. Did you check this?

Comment: @AlBundy As I stated in the question I have run the same query in phpMyAdmin and it works.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the question to show the connection code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parameterized queries, then you have to pass the value for the parameter when you execute the prepared query.

You also have to `execute` the prepared query. The prepare just passes the query to the database for compilation and optimisation, it does not actually execute the query.

Also if you get an error in these database access statement, there are functions/methods you should use to show the the actuall error message which are a lot more useful than outputting something you make up yourself like `echo "Error creating SQL statement";`

Also the `;` is not necessary.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?");
if ( $stmt === false ){
    echo $conn->error;
    exit;
}


$stmt->bindParam('i', $some_variable)

$result = $stmt->execute();

if ( $result === false ) {
    echo $stmt->error;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have passed a value for the parameter and executed the query. The error is occurring and triggering the `if` statement which is why I didn't include any code after that which is where the `bind` and `execute` are. In the question I asked how to get detailed error messages so why are you telling me that I need them rather than how to get them?

Comment: In that case, see the `if` test after the prepare, like I said, if you use the `mysqli_` error messages it will give you so much more to work with than inventing a useless error message of your own

Comment: I used `echo $stmt->error;` and got the following _Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object_.

Comment: If the `->prepare` fails you have to use `$conn->error;`. as `$stmt` is set to false and not a `mysqli_statement` object. _Refresh the page if you do not see the test after the `prepare`_

Comment: I did that and it doesn't show any error except the `echo` that I created.

Comment: So where did you put this new `if`? Edit your question and add your changed code as an EDIT. Dont overwrite your original question code

Comment: What do you mean this new `if`? I'm talking about the same `if` that is already there. I added the `echo $conn->error;` above the `echo"<p>failed to connect to database</p>";` however, no error gets echoed, I only see the message I made up.

Comment: Did you remove the `;` from the query

Comment: No but I have now and it hasn't made a difference, I don't know why it would considering all my other queries have `;` at the end and they all work.

Comment: Well I am grasping at straws, as `if ( $stmt === false)` there should be some sort of error message. Maybe if you amended you test to be that we could get somewhere

Comment: Testing a PHP variable that could be FALSE or an Object should always be done using `===` your `if(!$stmt)` is very unreliable

Comment: Then there is something going on here that we are not aware of.

Comment: Of course some un-checked error earlier on in the code may well be having some unexpected effect on this

Comment: I have added the entire main section of code from that page which includes all the php, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Close first connection using `mysqli_close($conn);` after first query is finished then open a new connection with `include 'connection.php';` before the second query. Credit to @Chay22